# Is there a wurfl python api?

Tags: python, api, wurfl

I am developing an web application on googleappengine with django.

I heard there is a wurfl php api of ScientiaMobile. But cannot find

for python users.

Is there any good wurfl python api that i can use ?

And also if it is exit, is there any nice manual for that api also?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Luca Passani, WURFL inventor and CTO of ScientiaMobile here.

ScientiaMobile supports Python in two ways:

- Through the integration with Python of its InFuze C/C++-based API: http://www.scientiamobile.com/page/wurfl-infuze-for-python-analytics
- Through a a Python "Cloud client", i.e. a script that will talk to an highly available always-updated WURFL REST service in the Cloud: http://www.scientiamobile.com/wurflCloud/gettingStarted

As far as the InFuze module goes, the product is meant for the enterprize and for those who need to do analysis of significant amounts of data with Python.

While the WURFL Cloud is not a free service in general, we do support a free offering for those who want to try the WURFL Cloud or use it for a low-traffic site. If this is for integration with an open-source project, feel free to contact me offline (email address is easily guessable) to understand together if there is something that we can do to support.

We do not support a standalone Python WURFL API. Not enough requests for it (contrary to what some believe, porting all the API logic to a new language is a big deal). What we support are products that integrate WURFL with Apache, NGINX and Varnish cache (this link has more info: http://www.scientiamobile.com/pr/scientiamobile_announces_availability_of_c_nginx_apache_varnish_api ). InFuze will inject WURFL capabilities directly into the context of the App server. Could this be ab option for the project too?

Answer (score -1):

There is a 51Degrees.mobi API for Python you could use which has better metrics than wurfl, they also have a Django package if desired. There is a guide and documentation on  their website: http://51degrees.mobi/Support/Documentation/Python/GettingStarted.aspx